# How to fix this bathroom light?

Tags: bathroom, light-fixture

This is my bathroom's light, which is both a light and a bathroom fan.

The light is much dimmer now, so I guess that one of the fluorescents (or lightbulbs) is out. The fan seems to be working well.

[image: lamp]

I have never seen this kind of model (I'm a expatriate, and this is nothing like I have seen in the country where I was born). I don't know how to manipulate the lamp to open it and replace the light (I'm afraid of cracking it when forcing it open). I don't even know the name of this particular lamp in order to look for some online tutorial, description or hints.

Any help abut how to manipulate the lamp open, how to replace the lights or even simply pointing to online resources about how to do it would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all I had to do was to pull gently. I was worried I would need to do something more complicated and I would crack it forcing it in a way it was not supposed to twist or open, but all I needed was to pull.

There were some wires that held the plastic lamp fixture to the ceiling, but I could separate it enough to get the lightbulbs.

[image]

I don't know what to do to replace the whole plastic part (and surely cleaning the inside is going to be challenging like this) but at least the lightbulbs can be reached this way.

Answer (score 1):

Reach up and tap the opaque lens cover. If it seems like it's not integrated into the rest of the housing, then you should be able to move it out of the way.

If it looks like it's one piece, then try lightly tugging on the whole thing, see if there's a spring loaded catch or retaining spring.

Comment: My house has the retaining spring type, and it took me forever to figure out you just pull down the whole fixture. Once you try it it's pretty easy to handle though.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach may be to think about how someone would have installed it in the first place. There must be some way to get to a fastener or hooks or latches to get it off the ceiling.

Use a flashlight and a wide-blade screwdriver to very gently see which portions of the cover (if any) flex away from the ceiling and which are tightly held to the ceiling. That will tell you where and perhaps how it's held on.

That cover may hinge, pry-off, or need a nudge in some direction to free it.